# How to copy streambuf to unsigned char array?

Tags: c++, boost, streambuf

how can I copy data in streambuf to a unsigned char array?
The code below have compiler errors:

```
boost::asio::streambuf buf;
std::ostream os(&buf);
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(os);
oa << m_data;

// allocate space for the buffer
unsigned char* output = (unsigned char*)malloc(buf.size());
buf >> output;
```

The compiler errors are (on the last line):

error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&' from 'boost::asio::streambuf'
1>          D:\program\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\istream(987) : see declaration of 'std::operator >>'

error C2676: binary '>>' : 'boost::asio::streambuf' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Comment: Please mention the compiler error message that you are seeing.

Comment: Programming by guessing doesn't work, bub!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After buffer allocation, you can fill it using [memcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) :

```
unsigned char* output = (unsigned char*)malloc(buf.size());
memcpy(output, boost::asio::buffer_cast<const void*>(buf.data()), buf.size());
```

Comment: Thanks, on the other way, do you know how can I copy the data in an unsigned char * array to the buf? I know I can use memcpy, however, are there simpler ways?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this without using raw memcpy. Having pointer to beginning of memory region, you could do

```
buf.sgetn(reinterpret_cast<char *>(output), buf.size());
```

This will copy first n bytes (`buf.size()` in this case), but also delete them from buffer, leaving non-copied bytes. Might be useful when your buffer is for example class member and you want to reuse it.